# Repeated Header Option Export Pdf and Excel in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Hi i am using jqgrid for displaying the data  and export data to pdf and excel format.i want to add header in each page in pdf and excel sheet i am attached the sample image 
[image]

I want to add Month,Head1,Head2,Head3 in each page in pdf and excel. i am searched in google but i am unable to find the option to enable repeated header in pdf,excel using jqgrid i am using the following option for exporting pdf and excel

```
        $("#export1").on("click", function(){
            $("#year_wise_rep").jqGrid("exportToPdf",{
                title: 'jqGrid Export to PDF',
                orientation: 'portrait',
                pageSize: 'A4',
                description: 'description of the exported document',
                customSettings: null,
                download: 'download',
                includeLabels : true,
                includeGroupHeader : true,
                includeFooter: true,
                fileName : "jqGridExport.pdf"
            })
        });                                      

        $("#export2").on("click", function(){
            $("#year_wise_rep").jqGrid("exportToExcel",{
                includeLabels : true,
                includeGroupHeader : true,
                includeFooter: true,
                fileName : "jqGridExport.xlsx",
                maxlength : 40 // maxlength for visible string data 
            })
        }) ;
```

please guide me to achieve the solution

Comment: Anyone know the answer

Answer (score 0):

The degree symbol can be exported if you copy and paste it in your colModel label property. The html tags for degree in pdf does not work. See the demo link below.

It is not possible programmatically to repeat the header table in excel. You may want to look at this [solution here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repeat-specific-rows-or-columns-on-every-printed-page-0d6dac43-7ee7-4f34-8b08-ffcc8b022409)

By default  a single header is printed repeated in pdf. In your case to print the multiple headers you will need to use onBeforeExport event in pdf export and the property headersRows set to 2. Please see the [docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/exporting/#export-to-pdf) .

See the [example here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/export/headerpdf/)

```
        $("#pdf").on("click", function(){
            $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('exportToPdf',{
                onBeforeExport : function( doc ) {
                    doc.content[0].table.headerRows = 2;
                }
            });
        });
```